# ERROR: eslint-bridge is unresponsive eventhough node.maxspace=16gb

Tags: java, node.js, docker, sonarqube

I got this error eventhough I tried to run `node --max-old-space-size=16384 ./sonarqube/sonar-project.js` nor use `sonar.javascript.node.maxspace=16384` inside `sonar-project.properties`:

```
ERROR: eslint-bridge Node.js process is unresponsive. This is most likely caused by process running out of memory. Consider setting sonar.javascript.node.maxspace to higher value (e.g. 4096).
ERROR: Failure during analysis, Node.js command to start eslint-bridge was: node --max-old-space-size=16384 /Github/project/.scannerwork/.sonartmp/eslint-bridge-bundle/package/bin/server 34111 127.0.0.1 /Github/project/.scannerwork true
java.lang.IllegalStateException: eslint-bridge is unresponsive
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.request(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:228)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.analyzeJavaScript(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:206)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.analyze(JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.java:132)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.runEslintAnalysis(JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.java:111)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.analyzeFiles(JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.java:80)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.AbstractEslintSensor.execute(AbstractEslintSensor.java:120)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.execute(JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.java:51)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:389)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:385)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:354)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
        at okhttp3.RealCall.timeoutExit(RealCall.java:108)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:97)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.request(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:221)
        ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Canceled
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:119)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:264)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

what's wrong with this?

Comment: Same problem here, when running inside a docker build with buildkit

Comment: @KeKru please take a look on my answer and try it if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a bit late answering my own question.

I managed to be able to resolve this issue, but not quite remember how do I did it.
But as I remember, the issue is not related with the node --max-old-space-size=16384 itself.

It is related with the `vm.max_map_count=262144`.
I didn't use the `--max-old-space-size` thing in my current project at all.

in case anyone looking to resolve the issue permanently (without manually add max_map_count when your machine restarted).

you can add below code to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing :) For now, it works when I increase from 4096 to 8192 by setting "sonar.javascript.node.maxspace=8192". But I come back to your answer, if it occurs again